# .xml layout is sending things(buttons, text etc) to the top left of the screen and want help to stop it from doing so

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an app for my studies and any time i try to move a item(button, text, etc) from the top left in design mode it doesn't move at all.

I've tried certain things to try fix it like changing the layout from relative to something different and nothing has changed. I've also turned on autoconnect but that just ruins the way the app looks on my phone.

i expect to be able to move my items away from the top corner without using autoconnect

Comment: you should post some of your layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">
```

or if you want to put it inside a relative layout, put android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" on the button